# MySQL Crosstab aggregation with 2 conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, crosstab

I have a query which creates a crosstab. The results are a count of the `txn_id` for `branda`, and the count of `txn_id` for `brandb`.

The txn_id is NOT UNIQUE. This is an example of the transactions table.:

```
txn_id | nationality_id | sku | sales | units

 1     |      1         |  1  |  20   | 2
 1     |      1         |  2  |  15   | 1
 2     |      4         |  1  |  20   | 2
 3     |      2         |  1  |  10   | 1
 4     |      3         |  2  |  15   | 1
 5     |      4         |  1  |  10   | 1
```

There are 2 other tables `(products) - (sku, brand, product name)`, and `(nationalities) - (nationality_id, nationality)`.

I would like to add a third column which gets me the count of `txn_id` where BOTH brands are purchased

The output should be

```
nationality | branda | brandb | combined

  1         |  1     |   1    |   1
  2         |  1     |   0    |   0
  3         |  0     |   1    |   0
  4         |  2     |   0    |   0
```

Current query.

```
SELECT 
    nationalities.nationality,
    COUNT((CASE brand WHEN 'branda' THEN txn_id ELSE NULL END)) AS branda,
    COUNT((CASE brand WHEN 'brandb' THEN txn_id ELSE NULL END)) AS brandb
 <I want my 3rd column here>
FROM
    transaction_data
        INNER JOIN
    products USING (sku)
        INNER JOIN
    nationalities USING (nationality_id)
GROUP BY nationality
ORDER BY branda DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

I have tried using:

`COUNT((CASE brand WHEN 'brandb' OR 'brandb' THEN txn_id ELSE NULL END)) AS combined` - however this obviously returns too many (returns branda or brandb regardless of whether they were purchased together). I know I can't use AND, because obviously no single cell is going to be both branda AND brandb.

I have also tried using:
`COUNT((CASE brand WHEN IN('branda', 'brandb') THEN txn_id ELSE NULL END)) AS combined` - However this isn't valid syntax.

I feel that I should be using a `HAVING` clause, but I'm not sure how this would work in the column list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are going to need two levels of aggregation:

```
SELECT n.nationality,
       sum(branda), sum(brandb), sum(branda * brandb)
FROM (SELECT t.txn_id, n.nationality,
             MAX(CASE brand WHEN 'branda' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS branda,
             MAX(CASE brand WHEN 'brandb' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS brandb
      FROM transaction_data t INNER JOIN
           products p
           USING (sku) INNER JOIN
           nationalities n
           USING (nationality_id)
      GROUP BY t.txn_id, n.nationality
     ) tn
GROUP BY n.nationality
ORDER BY max(txn_id) DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

Comment: This answer is valid and accepted, However it should be noted that this query will perform terribly on large tables (3M rows)

Comment: @AdamCopley . . . Is the performance really that much worse than your original query?

Comment: Yeah, it wouldn't run in less than a minute, (which is when I stopped it, so I broke it down into chunks and ran the `subquery` alone, that wouldn't run. then I stripped out the `txn_id` from the `column list` and `group by`, and got some results. I tell by these that had the `txn_id` been there, the set would be correct. I'll post some explains when I'm back at work monday to show you more detail about the indexes and lengths. The crap table structure i've inherited dsnt help much either with 1.5M distinct transaction id's out of 3.5M rows, with anywhere between 1 and 20 rows per `txn id`

Comment: @AdamCopley . . . Perhaps you should ask another question about how to improve the performance.  I should also note, though, that your original query really needs `count(distinct)` rather than `count()` to do what you want . . . and you might find that the distinct really kills the performance.

Comment: you are absolutely right too thinking about it, the way i'm doing it I'm getting a count of 2 when a certain brand is bought in the same basket twice, when it should be a 1.  Ohh dear, why did I think representing a few million with PHP/MySQL was a good idea!!